# how to check with jQuery if dropdown list has values which populates dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdown list City Offices which populates based on another select option of dropdown 'Country '.

When user select the Country dropdown then City Offices dropdown can be populated based on the selected country. But
not all the Country has City Offices thus city dropdown could be empty.

I am using ASP.Net MVC 4.8. The country selection execute a ajax method which calls the Controller's ActionMethod to get the values based on the Country dropdown value and get the City to populate city dropdown.

If City dropdown is empty then I do not want to check for the required field validation if City dropdown has list of options then I want to validate it as required field.

I am trying with the below code but for some reason it always find the if condition true and show the alert message. I suppose it should not show the alert message when the dropdown for the city is populated.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btnubmit').on("click", function () {


     if ($('#ddlStateList').has('option').length > 0)
     {
         alert("has value.");   

         if ($("#ddlStateList").val() === "") {
             $('#lbStateListError').show();
         }
     else 
         {
             $('#lbStateListError').hide();
           
         }
     }
  }
```

}

View

```
  @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()

                                .Name("ddlStateList")
                                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control", style = "width:100%" })
                                .DataValueField("StateName")
                                .DataTextField("StateName")
                                .AutoBind(false)
                                 .Events(e =>
                                 {
                                     e.Change("ddlchange")/*.Select("select")*/;
                                 })

                            )
```

The above code run at the submit button.

I tried to check the length with below code and it always return 0. even when city dropdown is populated

```
     var check = $('#ddlCityList option').length;
     console.log(check);
```

Comment: Please update with the HTML associated with this to create a fully reproducible example.  I would suggest a snippet with the jQuery version being used in it.

Comment: `if ($('#ddlStateList').has('option').length == 0)` should be `if ($('#ddlStateList').has('option').length > 0) //greater than zero => has options` ?

Comment: @OldPadawan  Methinks that is not even the proper approach here - and there seems to be something else in play here that we do not know at present.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: so you say you want to check CITY dropdown but your code appears to be checking the STATE dropdown.

Comment: You select control may have a single, blank option in it, that would screw this up. It's common to make the first option blank. You may want to check if the dropdown has any options with a non-blank value

Comment: You appear to be using Kendo UI which uses other html to simulate/proxy the dropdown. As far as I can tell, the simulated dropdown never has any actual `<option>` elements (it's all spans and such). So I'm surprised that you always get the popup rather than never getting the popup.

Comment: @Ouroborus I think Kendo uses a shadow `select` element, right? The display is done with  a ul and li, but it is built from a hidden `select`. At least, that's how a lot of those fancier drop downs work.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey It does. They have [demos](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/) of their various widgets. [DropDownList](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/index) uses the input element strangely, including keeping its descendants in a shadow dom and not using option elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you always have at least one option. it is common to have a SELECT control like:

```
<select name="cities"><option value="">Choose City...</option></select>
```

in which case, what you really need to do is check for an option with a value of any kind.

The selector doesn't appear to be good for this, probably best something like

```
    if ($("#ddlStateList").val() === "" && 
        $('#ddlStateList option').filter(function() { return $(this).val() !== ''; }).length > 0)
    {
        $('#lbStateListError').show();
    }
    else 
    {
        $('#lbStateListError').hide();
    }
```

`